# How to change the profile picture in whatsapp if the pictures is saved in a different folder?

Tags: lumia, whatsapp, lumia-520

i am using lumia 520. and whatsapp version i am using now is 2.11.494.0. i am not able to set a profile picture from a folder that is in my sd card. when i choose change profile pictures, it displays the default 4 folders(Camera Roll, Saved pictures,8 and screenshots).
I need to choose a picture which is not listed in these folders and it resides on a folder in sd card. In older versions of whatsapp i was able to do things like that. But i cant change it in the newer versions. Can someone help me with this issue

Comment: A new version of WhatsApp 2.11.504 is available in the store. Kindly update to see if the issue is resolved or you can [contact support](http://www.whatsapp.com/contact/) team at WhatsApp regarding the issue.

Comment: I'm guessing this is an app issue, which, as Vivek Parekh said, only the developers will be able to actually help with.

Comment: thank you drowin. The issue was fixed. It has nothing to do wit the app. its the win 8 error. Now i upgraded to 8.1 and all the app facilities are now available.

Answer (score 1):

If the previous answer didn't help you, You can try the [Files](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/files/762e837f-461d-4847-8399-3526f54fc25e) app (Official file manager) from the store. Use the app to move your pictures to the right folder and set your display picture.

Comment: i updated the version and still facing the same issue. I know that i can change my profile picture if i change the picture to the desired folder. I just want to know why sd card folders are displayed while selecting the profile picture in whatsapp